# Problem in provisioning when using stapling to customize sharepoint 2010 blog template

Tags: templates, sharepoint-2010, provisioning

I'm trying to use stapling to customize sharepoint 2010 blog template. I created a stapling feature and another feature for customizing the the site definition (onet.xml). It's work fine for web parts but if I include List Views  it gives an error  when I'm trying to  activate the  "customizing feature"  (Not the stapling feature)

Error is,

"Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Cannot complete this action."

This is the xml snippet which causes this problem. (I couldn't post the xml part here)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010programming/thread/6ba343f3-020b-47e5-938c-aeedcf094adc

BTW I'm trying to customize the default page here and my approach is

1) Get a copy of the existing custom page and rename and include in the feature

2) Change the master page of the above file to custom.master

3) Change the layout of the above page without removing "ContentPlaceHolders"

4) In feature element put module element copied from onet.xml

Appreciate if anyone can provide some insite on this.

Thanks

-Madhawa

Answer (score 0):

Try provisioning the file without the View to make sure that your Url and Path attributes are correct. Once an empty page is displaying, add the View XML back. For the List attribute, try using the relative URL path (ex. Lists/Blog) instead of the template ID.